# NullPointerException while launching an application from JNLP with Java 64 bit 1.7.0_06+

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jnlp, java-web-start

The following app works perfectly with Java 1.7.0_05 and older:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/demo/">
    <information>
        <title>BPI 4.7</title>
        <vendor>Fox Technical Services Inc.</vendor>
        <homepage href="/home.html"/>
        <description>Fox Client</description>
        <description kind="short">Fox</description>
        <icon href="base/Fox64.gif" height="64" width="64"/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="base/application.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="base/sessions.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/swingSessions.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/sharedClientServer.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/baseLookAndFeelNoDecorations.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/clientCommon2.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/httpProvider.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/swing.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/swingImages.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/glf.jar"/>
        <jar href="base/vnc.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/TableLayout-bin-jdk1.5-2007-04-21.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/dbswing.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/dx.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/beandt.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/jnlp.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/alloy.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/commons-beanutils.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/commons-logging.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/commons-lang-2.0.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/httpclient-4.0-beta2.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/httpcore-4.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/log4j-1.2.15.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/jbcl.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/mail-1.4.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="thirdPartyLib/activation-1.1.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="base/javolution.jar" download="lazy"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

When I try to run it with Java1.7.0_06 and newer, I get an exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.getMainClassName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The console logs are :

```
Java Web Start 10.7.2.11
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = C:\Users\val
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
Match: beginTraversal
Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.6+, heap=-1--1, args=null, href=http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_07
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: null
    native platform is: Windows, amd64 [ x86_64, 64bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.1 found at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

    Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1
    Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1
    Match: digesting vmargs: null
    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: JVM args after accumulation: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: digest LaunchDesc: null
    Match: digest properties: []
    Match: JVM args: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: endTraversal ..
    Match: JVM args final: 
    Match: Running JREInfo Version    match: 1.7.0.07 == 1.7.0.07
     Match: Running JVM args match: have:<>  satisfy want:<>
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### null
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try searching the bug DB/ raising a bug.  But be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) first.

Answer (score 0):

It feels strange that your application-desc element is empty.

According to the [jnlp-secification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) it must contain the attribute attribute **main-class**.

```
<application-desc main-class="com.yourcompany.MyCoolApplication" />
```